# Assets File Upload issue

Tags: ee2, assets

I have been having issues with the assets plugin in our new server and am having a hard time trying to debug.

When using ee file manager I get the below error. 
ee: 2.6.1, 
assets: 2.1.3

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1364

Field 'date' doesn't have a default value

INSERT INTO `exp_assets_files` (`file_name`, `source_type`, `source_id`, `filedir_id`, `folder_id`, `kind`) VALUES ('5551725767_38cb459f19_b.jpg', 'ee', NULL, '2', '1', 'image')

Filename: C:\www-customers\websitename\wwwrootV2\system\codeigniter\system\database\DB_driver.php
```

When uploading via assets the progress bar fades away and I receive and 200 response of

```
{"error":"There was an error uploading your file: Assets could not complete the requested operation."}
```

Paths and permissions are all (supposed to be) set up correctly. Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Hey,

is it possible to get CP and FTP access to this site? If so, send them over to support@pixelandtonic.com referencing this thread. Even if it's not possible, contact us there so we can start to debug this.

Comment: Hi Andris, I didn't see your reply.

After a bit of debugging, I found that the date field in the exp_assets_files table was set to not allow NULL and also did not have a default value. Checking the box to allow NULL and setting a defauly value of 0 fixed the problem and now images can be uploaded. My question is, why does this happend and how come the date is not correctly being added to the database?

Comment: Ben,

I haven't seen MySQL complain about this before so I'll asume some strict settings on the server. This *is* an oversight on our part, however, and we'll fix it with the next Assets release.

As for the other part of the question about the date not being correctly added - we add the file first, then we process the meta-data, such as size, height/width (for images) etc and then add that to the already-created row in the table.

Are you still having some issues?

Comment: I can confirm everything is now working :D

Comment: Well there you go then :)

I suggest posting your fix as an answer and accepting for some sweet, sweet karma!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of debugging, I found that the date field in the exp_assets_files table was set to not allow NULL and also did not have a default value. Checking the box to allow NULL and setting a defauly value of 0 fixed the problem and now images can be uploaded.